# How to deaggregate a json array from the transformation function to use dynamic partitioning in Firehose

Tags: python, json, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm receiving, from the broker (aws iot) the messages I want to pass on to firehose like this (array of json):

```json
"payload": "{\"timestamp\":1696338507228,\"metrics\":[{\"name\":\"X\",\"timestamp\":1696338505457,\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"value\":10.0}, {\"name\":\"Y\",\"timestamp\":1696338505457,\"dataType\":\"Float\",\"value\":20.0}]
```

Firehose encodes the payload (Base64) and sends to the lambda, where I'm able to do some transformations and return the data. The issue is that I have only a recordid per document so I have to return them as an array of json also:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []
    # do some stuff and filtering
    
    # add the partitionKey for each record:
    filtered_data = [dict(item, **{'partitionKey':'name'}) for item in filtered_data]
    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        payload_dict = json.loads(payload)
        
         output.append(
                {
                'recordId': f"{record['recordId']}",
                'result': 'Ok',
                'data': base64.b64encode(combined_filtered_data.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),  # Serialize the JSON record
               } 
     return {'records': output}
```

I receive the data back in KFH but I don't know how to handle it to have the data partitioned by name value for each json object

I tried passing the metadata with the records but it seems adequate only for one record and not an array (in this case my S3 bucket prefix is !{partitionKeyFromLambda:name}

```py
 output.append(
            {
            'recordId': f"{record['recordId']}",
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(combined_filtered_data.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),  
            'metadata': 'metadata': {'partitionKeys': {'name': 'X'}}
```